# Find parent and first child of it's parent

Tags: jquery, parent, children, css-selectors

I am trying to find the parent of an element and it's parent first child, the code is like this:

```
        <ul class="lowerMenu">
            <li><a href="" class="selected">Welcome</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Websites</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Stationery</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Illustration</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Full Pack</a></li>
        </ul>

function setIntervalAndExecute() {
    changeImages();
    setTimeout(function(){
        showImages(imagesArray);
    },500);
    var intervalot = window.setInterval(function(){
        changeImages();
        var selected = $('.selected');
        if (!selected.parent().is(':last-child')) {
            $('.selected').parent().next().children().addClass('selected');
            selected.removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            $('.selected').parent().parent().children(':first-child').addClass('selected');
            selected.removeClass('selected'); // nesho ne mi rabotit ovdeki
        }
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            showImages(imagesArray);
        },500);
    },10000);
    return intervalot;
}
var intervalot = setIntervalAndExecute();
```

I know it's a little complicated but i'm new to jquery , so what i'm trying to do is after the class 'selected' gets to the last  element i want to remove it and set it to the first  element. I've tried with this but it doesn't seem to be working

```
$('.selected').parent().parent().children(':first-child').addClass('selected');
```

and when it gets to the last  element the interval is executing twice and then stops.
This is the site that i'm working on:

> http://nikodola.com/testsite

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you go up two levels, then find the next child, you're only going down one level -- you're setting the `selected` class on the `<li>`, not the `<a>` below it.. You need to go down another level. So it should be:

```
$('.selected').parent().parent().children(':first-child').children().addClass('selected');
```

Another way to get there is:

```
$('.selected').parent().siblings(':first-child').children().addClass('selected');
```

Comment: perfect , thank you very much :D i knew it was something small and stupid .. but instead child() i put children() cause it was not working like that

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.selected').parent().siblings(':first-child').children().addClass('selected');
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/64zGF/)**

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.selected').closest('ul').find('li:first').addClass('selected');
```

reference [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score -1):

There is no need of total traversing back to the parent one after the other in a hierarchy, you can just do use `parents()` instead of `parent()` in this way

```
$('.selected').parents('ul.lowerMenu').children(:first-child').addClass('selected');
```

Try it this is working!!