I need to give an element the same class as another element
<div class='topnav' id='myTopnav'>
  <div class='dropdown'>
    <button class=' dropbtn'>Adobe &#x25BC;</button>
    <div class='dropdown-content'>
        <a href='index'>Photoshop</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var path = window.location.href;
        $('#myTopnav a').each(function() {
            if (this.href === path) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().parent('first-child').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

I am not very good at jQuery or even Javascript, but I would like to give the button the same class as the anchor tag when the url the anchor is pointing to is correct.

$(this).closest('.dropdown').find('button') should get you the button, if that’s the trouble.

A similar approach to how you already tried it is outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18531398 ($(this).parent().parent().children(':first-child'))

Select your options and add class.
$('select#your-select-id option').addClass('your-class-name');


I've not working with JQuery for a long time but here is my suggestion.
You can try this one
First, find the closet dropdown after that find dropbtn
$(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropbtn').addClass('active');

For finding .dropbtn class as i remember it's may return all element that have .dropbtn so if you're in this case I think you may need to get first.
Hope it's can help
